# ListBox "IsSelected" binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have searched high and low for an answer to this problem with no luck, from what I can see I have all the correct elements in place but for some reason this does not want to work.

I require the IsSelected setter to run when a item is selected in the ListBox.

XAML code

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="226" Margin="10,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}" >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     </ListBox>
```

C# ViewModel

```
 private bool m_isSelected;
 public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return m_isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value != m_isSelected)
            {
                m_isSelected = value;

                if (m_isSelected)
                {
                    CurrentViews = getCurrentViews((BasePropertyTypeVM)CurrentActivity);
                    AvailableViews = getAvailableViews(Properties);
                }

                OnPropertyChanged(() => IsSelected);
            }
        }
    }
```

Many Thanks,

Sam

Comment: And you have set a breakpoint in the setter and checked that it isn't hit?

Comment: Yea I have used a breakpoint on the setter, it is never called.

Comment: Just to double check, your IsSelected property is on Activity ViewModel right? and not on the parent VM.

Comment: If getCurrentViews or getAvailableViews runs into an exception the setter will not work

Comment: @Clemens `DataContext.IsSelected` with `RelativeSource Self` Will it work???

Comment: Yes the IsSelected is in the same viewmodel as the Activity collection.

Comment: @ernodeweerd Even if i comment both of these out the setter is never hit

Comment: Are there any binding errors in the debug output?

Comment: The listbox is bound to a Activities observable collection with its own getter and setter E.g private ObservableCollection<string> _activities = new ObservableCollection<String>();

Comment: BindingExpression path error: 'IsSelected' property not found on 'object' ''ActivityPropertiesView' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsSelected; DataItem='ActivityPropertiesView' (Name=''); target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'IsSelected' (type 'Boolean')

Comment: Im thinking that means its looking in the activities object for the IsSelected field, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IsSelected` property of the ListBoxItem is bound to the `IsSelected` view model property, which must be a property of the data item type, i.e. the element type of the `Activities` collection.

You need to declare such a data item class, e.g.

```
public class Activity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value != isSelected)
            {
                value = isSelected;
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

and declare the `Activities` collection like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Activity> { get; set; }
```

The `Name` property of the Activity class could be used in a DataTemplate of the ListBoxItem:

```
<ListBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding Activites}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding DataContext.IsSelected, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" />
```

Comment: This is now triggering the setter, however its selecting everything in the ListBox, any ideas?

Comment: @SamEmber Your IsSelected property should'nt be in the ViewModel that contains your Activities ObservableCollection. Instead IsSelected should be in 'Activity' ViewModel or you should have SelectedItem property in your parent ViewModel and bind to it instead in the ListBox xaml.

Comment: Look at Clemens answer, it simplifies everything for you.

Comment: @SamEmber Think about it. You need one IsSelected property for each item, i.e. one for each element in the Activities collection. The solution presented here does not do what you want, because it binds the IsSelected property of all ListBoxItems to the same property, which can only have one value. Hence all items are either selected or not.

Comment: @Clemens Yea that makes perfect sence, thanks for your help Clemens